# How to use numba to speed up spsolve?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, sparse-matrix, numba

When I use spsolve to solve large sparse linear system, I have to iterate the solver again and again to approximate the solution. However, when I use numba.njit, it tells me

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'spsolve': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>

File "<ipython-input-5-015f4b4a615e>", line 14:
def func(b):
    x = spsolve(A, b)
    ^
```

My codes are the followings

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
row  = np.array([0, 0, 1, 3, 2])
col  = np.array([0, 2, 1, 3, 2])
data = np.array([1, 2, 4, 5, 7])
coo = coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(4, 4))
A = coo.tocsr()
b = np.ones((4,1))

@njit
def func(b):
    x = spsolve(A, b)
    return x

func(b)
```

Then it shows me the above error. How could I speed up using numba? **Really worried.** Please help me. Thx

Comment: `Numba translates Python functions to optimized machine code at runtime` `spsolve` is mostly C compiled / native code. numba won't be able to touch this. And as spsolve-computations is probably dominating python loop-iteration overhead easily, i don't see any merit in using numba.

Comment: The fact is when I implement the loop it takes more than half an hour. So I need to speed up. The true sparse matrix is around size (200, 200) and it remains unchanged. The iteration is to treat the iterated b as the old one and iterate with it again and again.

Comment: `numba` works with the code that you've written (and a large subset of `numpy`).  It cannot 'reach into" `scipy` code to "compile" that.  That applies to both `spsolve` and the `sparse` code.  `sparse.csr` matrix multiplication already uses `cython` code.

Comment: Thx. I think I should try iterative methods to solve it.

Comment: Just now, I try all the methods including all sorts of iterative methods, multigrid methods, sparse direct solvers. They don't work. I still need a lot of time.

Comment: Why not use a direct solver? 200x200 is not a large system at all.

Comment: Sparse direct solver is actually the LU decomposition method. I %timeit one calculation and it takes around 70 ms. I have more than 15000 calculations to obtain the approximate solution so it is not practicable. Yesterday I tried all the method and use petsc4py to spped up successfully. Many thanks.

Comment: @A_99 is there any helpful documentation of petsc4py that I can use to start from scratch?