# Need help in solving a sparse system in python; spsolve with Numba

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra, numba

I have a sparse system Ax=b, provided that the Matrices are in csr format. I want to speed it up using Numba. But I get an error, TypeError: return type must be specified for object mode. I got an idea that spsolve can not be applied in Numba but is there any other alternative to speed up the sparse system?
I am using the reference from [How to use numba to speed up spsolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65186861/how-to-use-numba-to-speed-up-spsolve), but still, it is not clear to me.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: As I noted in your link `numba` can't work with `csr` matrix.

Comment: Yes, I checked that also. There is a Numba-Scipy module which according to the documentation https://pypi.org/project/numba-scipy/ supports numba for csr matrices. But I could not find any relevant example to check how to implement it.

Comment: Your link does not specifically mention sparse matrices (or any other subpackage).  From the dates and files, it looks like a start of the project, not a complete awareness.  At best it may handle some of the "special" functions.